# How do i change the colors of the bar inside this asp.net chartcontrol in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

For my project i need to make 3 bar charts in asp.net that shows 3 different statusses. i'm using a sqldatasource. i can't make series because that messes up the order of the chart
this is my code for the chart:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart3" style="border-radius: 0 !important;" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="Naam" ChartType="StackedColumn" YValueMembers="Aantal">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

I dont use any C# code
How can i change the colors?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "i can't make series because that messes up the order of the chart"?

Each series is shown in the same order in which you have added them in ASPX file. Unless of course you are changing it in backend C# code.

You can change the color of each bar by adding separate series for each of the status and then use the Color property to specify color that you want for each series. All three series should refer to same chart area.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31477285)